# Make an azure logic app run in the future, not repeat

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I wonder that do we have a way to make a logic app to run in the specific date in the future and no repeat, I use Recurrence trigger but it required an interval.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the Microsoft documentation to run a logic app in the future only once and not repeat the run.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/concepts-schedule-automated-recurring-tasks-workflows#run-one-time-only

It uses the Delay-Until action in Azure logic Apps to achieve it.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-delay#add-the-delay-until-action

Comment: @Nhat Duy - Did the Delay-Until action in Azure Logic Apps solve your issue ?